# Select majority number of each row in matrix using r

Tags: r

I have a matrix with varing number of columns of the following form:

```
1  10  10 10 15
2  14  14 13 13
4  19  19 20 21
6  32  32 20 15
```

I would like to select the majority for each row producing the following output:

```
1  10
2  14/13
3  19
4  32
```

Comment: Just for educational purposes, what you're looking for is called the "mode."  `table` is the easiest way to find modes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seemed like `table` almost gives what you need, but the output must be massaged.  `Compose` is an interesting way to do this:

```
require(functional)
apply(m, 1, Compose(table,
                    function(i) i==max(i),
                    which,
                    names,
                    function(i) paste0(i, collapse='/')
                    )
      )

## [1] "10"    "13/14" "19"    "32"
```

Comment: can I do the same but omit the first column?

Comment: You can.  Replace `m` with `m[-1,,drop=FALSE]`.  Similarly to omit the first column, use `m[,-1,drop=FALSE]`.

Answer (score 9):

One of the possible answers:

```
# over each row of data.frame (or matrix)
sapply(1:nrow(x), function(idx) {
# get the number of time each entry in df occurs
    t <- table(t(x[idx, ]))
# get the maximum count (or frequency)
    t.max <- max(t)
# get all values that equate to maximum count
    t <- as.numeric(names(t[t == t.max]))
})
```

Comment: this is great, what if I would like to omit the first column?

Comment: @user1723765 instead of the `table` command given, use `table(t(x[idx,-1]))`

Answer (score 4):

late addition, but when values are all positive, as in your example, you can also:

```
apply(x, 1, function(idx) {
     which(tabulate(idx) == max(tabulate(idx)))
     })
```

without first column:

```
 apply(x[,-1], 1, function(idx) {
     which(tabulate(idx) == max(tabulate(idx)))
     })
```

and finally tweak your output:

```
s <- apply(x[,-1], 1, function(idx) {
     which(tabulate(idx) == max(tabulate(idx)))
     })
sapply(s, paste, sep="", collapse="/")

[1] "10"    "13/14" "19"    "32"
```

Comment: For the last line, an anonymous function is not required: `sapply(s, paste, sep="", collapse="/")`

Comment: thanks @MatthewLundberg I have a habit of typing them out as default