# R calculate mode for a row, not a column

Tags: r

Usually people want to calculate mode from each question, but in my case I need to calculate the mode for each respondente, across all questions.

This is how my data looks like:

```
> head(TiposMotivA)
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10 Q11 Q12 Q13 Q14 Q15 Q16 Q17 Q18 Q19 Q20 Q21
1  5  4  4  4  6  6  7  6  4   6   6   6   4   4   4   4   6   7   4   4   6
2  5  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5   5   7   5   4   3   1   6   6   5   6   7   7
3  4  5  4  4  5  4  5  4  5   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   5
4  5  5  7  7  4  6  6  6  7   7   6   7   7   6   6   7   4   7   6   6   7
5  6  1  7  6  7  7  7  7  7   7   6   7   2   2   3   6   3   7   7   7   7
6  4  4  3  3  4  5  4  3  4   7   6   6   4   4   6   4   5   7   6   6   7
```

This Solution was the best I found so far:

```
apply(TiposMotivA, 1, Compose(table,
                    function(i) i==max(i),
                    which,
                    names,
                    function(i) paste0(i, collapse='/')
                    )
      )
```

It was provided by Matthew Lundberg here: [Select majority number of each row in matrix using r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114046/select-majority-number-of-each-row-in-matrix-using-r)

It produced this:

```
 [1] "4"   "5"   "4"   "7"   "7"   "4"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7" 
[14] "5/6" "7"   "6"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"
[27] "7"   "7"   "7"   "5"   "2"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "6"   "6"   "7"
[40] "4/7" "3"   "4"   "7"   "5/7" "6"   "7"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"
[53] "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"   "5/7" "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"  
>
```

My problem, which might seem basic for some, is driving me nuts.
I need only one mode per row, so when there are two, I need simply the first.
I have tried to use split() without success.

So, what I need is to get mode for each row, as presented above, but having only the first mode when there are two.

Something like this:

```
 [1] "4"   "5"   "4"   "7"   "7"   "4"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7" 
[14] "5" "7"   "6"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"
[27] "7"   "7"   "7"   "5"   "2"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "6"   "6"   "7"
[40] "4" "3"   "4"   "7"   "5" "6"   "7"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"
[53] "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"   "5" "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"  
>
```

Any help is gonna be pretty appreciated.

Comment: Perfect akrun, as Always worked like a charm!. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to change from "wide" to "long" format using `melt`, convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" with `setDT`, get the count (`.N`), grouped by variables ("Var1", "value"), find the index of maximum value of "N" (`which.max(N)`) and use that to get the "value", grouped by "Var1"

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
setDT(melt(as.matrix(TiposMotivA)))[, .N ,.(Var1, value)][,
                             value[which.max(N)], Var1]$V1
#[1] 4 5 4 7 7 4
```

Or you could use `base R` functions (modified from the link)

```
apply(TiposMotivA, 1, function(idx) which.max(tabulate(idx)))
#1 2 3 4 5 6 
#4 5 4 7 7 4
```

Answer (score 4):

`which.max` can be used to find the position of the first maximum:

```
apply(TiposMotivA, 1, function(x) { tab <- table(x); names(tab)[which.max(tab)] } )
```

giving:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6 
"4" "5" "4" "7" "7" "4"
```

No packages are needed.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you found will paste together all of the modes, we can modify it a little bit to just give you the first mode:

```
apply(TiposMotivA, 1, Compose(table,
                    function(i) i==max(i),
                    which,
                    names,
                    function(i) i[1]
                    )
      )
```

Comment: Perfect tkmckenzie, as Always worked like a charm too!. Many thanks!